# How to use symbols/punctuation characters in discriminated unions

Tags: f#, symbols, discriminated-union

I'm trying to create a discriminated union for part of speech tags and other labels returned by a natural language parser.

It's common to use either strings or enums for these in C#/Java, but discriminated unions seem more appropriate in F# because these are distinct, read-only values.

In the language reference, I found that this symbol 

``` ``...`` ```
 can be used to delimit keywords/reserved words. This works for

``` type ArgumentType =

| A0 // subject

| A1 // indirect object

| A2 // direct object

| A3 //

| A4 //

| A5 //

| AA //

| ``AM-ADV`` ```

However, the tags contain symbols like $, e.g.

``` type PosTag =

| CC //     Coordinating conjunction

| CD //     Cardinal Number

| DT //     Determiner

| EX //     Existential there

| FW //     Foreign Word

| IN //     Preposision or subordinating conjunction

| JJ //     Adjective

| JJR //    Adjective, comparative

| JJS //    Adjective, superlative

| LS //     List Item Marker

| MD //     Modal

| NN //     Noun, singular or mass

| NNP //    Proper Noun, singular

| NNPS //   Proper Noun, plural

| NNS //    Noun, plural

| PDT //    Predeterminer

| POS //    Possessive Ending

| PRP //    Personal Pronoun

| PRP$ //$  Possessive Pronoun

| RB //     Adverb

| RBR //    Adverb, comparative

| RBS //    Adverb, superlative

| RP //     Particle

| SYM //    Symbol

| TO //     to

| UH //     Interjection

| VB //     Verb, base form

| VBD //    Verb, past tense

| VBG //    Verb, gerund or persent participle

| VBN //    Verb, past participle

| VBP //    Verb, non-3rd person singular present

| VBZ //    Verb, 3rd person singular present

| WDT //    Wh-determiner

| WP //     Wh-pronoun

| WP$ //$   Possessive wh-pronoun

| WRB //    Wh-adverb

| ``#``

| ``$``

| ``''``

| ``(``

| ``)``

| ``,``

| ``.``

| ``:``

| `` //not sure how to escape/delimit this ```

``` ``...`` ```
 isn't working for WP$ or symbols like (

Also, I have the interesting problem that the parser returns `` as a meaningful symbol, so I need to escape it as well.

Is there some other way to do this, or is this just not possible with a discriminated union?

Right now I'm getting errors like

- Invalid namespace, module, type or union case name
- Discriminated union cases and exception labels must be uppercase identifiers

I suppose I could somehow override toString for these goofy cases and replace the symbols with some alphanumeric equivalent?

Comment: Why don't you simply use a naming convention that fits instead of use the literal from the parser?

Answer (score 1):

The spec doesn't seem clear about what characters are allowed to be escaped in double-backticks in what contexts.

I think your best bet is to use standard identifiers for the DU cases, and override `ToString` as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, double-backtick marks identifiers are/seem to be fully supported only in let Bindings or type members. So that means you can put about any sequence of characters inside (excepting the `@` character which is reserved for F# codegen).

When you want to use them as identifiers in module, type or DU cases definition, it doesn't play as nice since some characters are not supported.

E.g. `.`, `/`, `*`, `+`, `$`, `[`, `]`, `\` or `&`  generate an "Invalid namespace, module, type or union case name" error.